# Flutter: How can i make multiple screens for each element of nested list?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I want to implement App as like given reference App, So i'm looking for that Logic.

i have implemented logic for add various elements into list but how can i make multiple screens on tap of ListTile

for reference app visit :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tuyware.jsongenie

Please someone go through it ,Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Example Project.
I hope it is useful for you.
If it does not work feel free to ask me for better solution.

https://github.com/phucgaoxam/demo_navigator_flutter

thanks

Comment: it is a best way to work with fragment in flutter